# UNIX shell script: using "case" to validate user's input

Tags: shell-script, case

I am trying to validate user's input So input is a number not 
a string or null. using case I tried to do this

```
echo "input a number"
read num1

case $num1 in 
"" |*[a-zA-Z]*)
echo "please inter a valid number"
esac

echo "input 2nd number"
read num2



let sum=$num1+$num2
echo "$num1 + $num2=$sum"
```

But it didn't quite work.
It gives me the warning about the input though -- 
And is there away to validate both variables at the sametime?

Answer (score 1):

To check both variables at once, you can concatenate and check.

Here is the part that changes:

```
case $num1$num2 in 
'' |*[!0-9]*)
    echo "please enter a valid number"
    exit
    ;;
```

You can also use `exit` to exit right after printing the error.

Comment: Thanks @amisax But why it is not working for NULL?

Comment: @user128174 , I have changed that part too. You need to use single quotes instead of double quotes  in the `case`

Comment: Thanks again! Now what should I do to exit when the first input is is not a number or null?  right now the program waits until the second input to be entered to print the error

Comment: then you really want to do this one by one.  The efficient ways to check the same can be seen here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

Using bash you can use a regular expression to validate the number:

```
#! /bin/bash
while [ -z "$REPLY" ]; do
    read -p "Enter a valid number: "
    if ! [[ "$REPLY" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
        echo Bad number: $REPLY
        REPLY=
    fi
done
echo A valid number: $REPLY
```

The program keeps reading input until the variable `$REPLY` is set by `read`. When the number is matched right against `^[0-9]+$` the loop is ended.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom function for doing that.

```
# func def.
isInt() {
    case ${1-} in '' | *[!0-9]* ) return 1 ;; esac
    return 0
}

# now use it as:
if isInt "$num1"; then
   echo "$num1 is a valid integer"
else
   echo "$num1 is not an integer"
fi
```

Note that `case` uses wildcards and not regexes for it's job.