# Checking for numeric arguments

Tags: bash, arguments

I want to check function arguments, and check whether `$2` and `$3` are numeric
Is the following line the way to use the `AND` statement?  Am I using `=` the correct way to check for numeric digits?

```
if [[ "$2" = +([[:digit:]]) ]] && [[ "$3" = +([[:digit:]]) ]]; then
```

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: Also, what you really want to match is: <beginning of string><1 or more digits><end of string>. What you have matches a string with a digit in it. Test cases: `"a1a", "1a", "129"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if an input number is an integer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151654/checking-if-an-input-number-is-an-integer)

Comment: @waltinator It is not so. `"a1a"` returns false, whilst `"123"` returns true.

Comment: I do get confused on whether to use `=` or `==`.  Is there any general rule?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a function, perhaps called "IsInt", which returns true if the parameters passed is numeric. You would then say

```
if IsInt "$2" && IsInt "$3" ; then
...
fi
```

You then have the simpler task of creating "IsInt", or looking at [an existing answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375956/194382)